# How to send recorded audio to server in JS?

Tags: javascript, audio, send, audio-recording

I am calling function uploadAudioFromBlob which save recorded audio to my server to location, where is this function saved so the destination: /tmp/record_speech_test/. It works, but I want to send recorded sounds to server to save it to school server. I have IP address of school's server and port number. Recorded sound is in WAV, 44,1kHz stereo. It seems easy but I am new in JS. Thanks a lot guys. I want to implement sending recordered audio direct in JS.

```js
function uploadAudioFromBlob(blob)
{
    console.log(blob);
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    // this is triggered once the blob is read and readAsDataURL returns
    reader.onload = function (event) 
    {
        var formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append('audio', event.target.result); 
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST'
            , url: 'http://ip_adress/tmp/record_speech_test/upload.php'
            , data: formData   
            , processData: false 
            , contentType: false 
            , dataType: 'json' 
            , cache: false 
            , success: function (data)  
            {
                console.log(data); 
            }
            , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  
            {
                alert('Error! '+ textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: Where is the full code which also records ?

Comment: @Royi JavaScripts which provide recording are "recorder.js" and "recorderWorker.js". You can see them on this site: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: Thanks. I didnt find which browser support this though. it seems [not many at all](http://jsbin.com/gahose/1/quiet?q=getUserMedia)

Comment: Regarding your question , does your school has any iis/nodejs/server which can accept uploads ?

Comment: School's server allow users to upload their data, I can upload for example: audio or text to this server.

Comment: @Royi I have found out that our school's server has implemented application, which will use this recorded audio. It is called  "SpeechRecoClient 3" . This application needs only IP address of school server, port number of school server, name of recorded audio but this items are configured and this application is usable to work. I only want to send audio to this server for use by this application.